# Looping through a dictionary for calculation

Tags: python

I'm brand new if you can't tell.

I want to loop through each dictionary, so that I can calculate the total worth of the 'menu' but i have no idea how to construct the loop.

Please help...

```
menu = ["Cappuccino", "Espresso", "Latte", "Macchiato"]
stock = {"Cappuccino": 24,
         "Espresso": 18,
         "Latte": 39,
         "Macchiato": 43}
price = {"Cappuccino": 4.36,
         "Espresso": 1.70,
         "Latte": 3.25,
         "Macchiato": 1.80}
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement

Comment: `sum(price.values())` does it in one fell swoop :)

Comment: Now, if you want the total value of the STOCK (in which case you might want to edit your question), this will do it: `sum(stock[item]*price[item] for item in menu)`

Comment: it would be better not to have separate dictionaries for stock and price. Use nested dictionaries: `{"Capuccino": {"price": 4.36, "stock": 24}, ...}`. Keeping all related data together simplifies the rest of the code.

Comment: As @Barmar said (and you can get rid of `menu` at the same time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the for loop for this.
I assume you want to sum the number of each element multiplied by the nummber ofelements in stock

```
total_price = 0 

for item in menu:
    total_price += price[item] * stock[item]
    
print(total_price)
```

total_price will have the total value of your stock

Comment: `price(key)` should be `price[key]`

Comment: You can just loop through the values instead of the keys: `for value in price.values():`

Comment: I understood better the question and corrected, I didn't understand the point of the stock beforehand, this should be correct

Comment: Just use list comprehension with `total_price = sum([q * p for q, p in zip(stock.values(), price.values())])`